# how i make this texture to have rotation but with a large scale at the same time?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

this procedural texture i scale it at 40 k in one axis, but if i try the rotation like for 45 deg or so in that same mapping node it doesn't get affected how i want, it doesnt rotate the whole texture, so how can i make the nodes to work to have a rotation and scale like that? thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSWK.png)

Comment: guys help me please..

Comment: Did you try adding a mapping node with your rotation right after the texture coordinate node and before all the others ?

Comment: @Gorgious thanks for saying that i found the solution!

Comment: Glad that helped !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after playing around with math and vertor math for some reason it gives interesting effects but not what i was looking for, so i found the solution after someone above in the comments give me an idea which was quite the solution, i just had to invert the mapping node inputs and then it worked
[image]